# eslint is not getting disabled for specific file

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to create Notes.ts file for making notes of typescript. I need syntax highlighting but no eslint. How can i stop eslint to stop working for my notes file.

MyDir Structure

```
root/.eslintignore
root/NestJS.ts
root/package.json
```

NestJS.ts Contents

```
/* eslint-disable */

import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('/app')
export class AppController {
  @Get('/asdf')
  getRootRoute() {
    return 'hi there!';
  }

  @Get('/bye')
  getByeThere() {
    return 'bye there!';
  }
}
```

.eslintignore contents

```
**/*.js
**/*.ts
NestJs.ts
```

package.json contents

```
{
  "name": "notes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "NestJS.ts",
    "world.js"
  ]
}
```

even after adding /* eslint-disable */, eslint is showing me errors !!!

Comment: nestJs and nestJS both are different, could this be the issue?

Comment: Fixed that too still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file .eslintignore in the root catalog. The format of this file matches the format of .gitignore and you can add there not only files but directories too.

Comment: Tried that not working